# mouseclick and mousemove events giving offset errors in react canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

### Premise

I am trying to convert my simple javascript canvas into React.js code. I am having trouble setting up mouse click and mouse move events in React.js.

### Error

I am getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetLeft' of undefined
    at HTMLCanvasElement.click_buildings

TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetLeft' of undefined
HTMLCanvasElement.onMouseMove
```

I guess either mouse events don't bind or it cannot read some values because of scope. I can't figure out which one it is, or how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance!

### Code

Here is my code below:

```
class Economy extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      this.updateCanvas();
      let source = null;
    }
    updateCanvas() {
      const canvas = this.refs.gameScreen;
      let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      const canvas_buildings = this.refs.buildings;
      const ctx_buildings = canvas_buildings.getContext("2d");
      canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMove, false);
      canvas.addEventListener("click", this.click, false);
      canvas_buildings.addEventListener("click", this.click_buildings, false);
      let assigned_cordinates = [];
      var img = new Image();
      var img_copper = new Image();
      img_copper.src = Copper;
      img_copper.onload = function() {
        ctx_buildings.drawImage(img_copper, 0, 0, 90, 120);
    }
    onMouseMove(e) {
      var x = e.clientX - this.canvas.offsetLeft;
      var y = e.clientY - this.canvas.offsetTop;
      var x_cord = Math.trunc(x / 90);
      var y_cord = Math.trunc(y / 120);
      if (this.assigned_cordinates.indexOf(this.old_x + "" + this.old_y) === -1) {
        this.ctx.clearRect(this.old_x * 90, this.old_y * 120, 90, 120);
      }
      if (this.assigned_cordinates.indexOf(x_cord + "" + y_cord) === -1) {
        if (this.source === "copper") {
          this.ctx.drawImage(this.img_copper, x_cord * 90, y_cord * 120, 90, 120);
        } else if (this.source === "none") {
        }
      }
      this.old_x = x_cord;
      this.old_y = y_cord;
    }
    click(e) {
      console.log(this.assigned_cordinates);
      var x = e.clientX - this.canvas.offsetLeft;
      var y = e.clientY - this.canvas.offsetTop;
      var x_cord = Math.trunc(x / 90);
      var y_cord = Math.trunc(y / 120);
      if (this.assigned_cordinates.indexOf(x_cord + "" + y_cord) === -1) {
        if (this.source === "copper") {
          this.ctx.drawImage(this.img_copper, x_cord * 90, y_cord * 120, 90, 120);
          this.assigned_cordinates.push(x_cord + "" + y_cord);
        } else if (this.source === "none") {
        }
      }
    }
    click_buildings(e) {
      var x = e.clientX - this.canvas_buildings.offsetLeft;
      var x_cord_buildings = Math.trunc(x / 90);
      if (x_cord_buildings === 0) {
        this.source = "copper";
      }
    }
    render() {
      return(
        <div className="screens">
            <canvas ref="buildings" className="buildings" width={800} height={100}/>
            <canvas ref="gameScreen"  className="gameScreen" width={800} height={600}/>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that `this.canvas` is not defined in the **scope** you are trying to access it from. I am assuming this `const canvas = this.refs.gameScreen;`  is the canvas  you are trying to access. If this is true then it complains about undefined because it exists only in `updateCanvas() {...}` and you are trying to access it from outside `updateCanvas()`

You'll need to define canvas somewhere it is accessible throughout your component. Maybe in props or something, I am not farmiliar with react so I don't know where exactly component data is defined. In Vue it would in data.